# fairy tale or historical

Tags: word-usage

Is the following use of "historical" okay?

> What's your favorite literary genre? Fairy tale or historical?

I'm wondering if "historical" can be short for historical fiction.

Comment: It can't. That's why there is the term "historical fiction". It seems to me that you are making up definitions for words hoping they will be accepted. Pretty weird.

Comment: Can "horror" alone stand for "horror movie"?

Comment: "Historical" by itself fails to differentiate between historical fiction and historical non-fiction.

Comment: Dude. You're still doing it. Horror, like historical fiction, is a genre. If you say "horror", nobody knows what you mean.

Comment: @CanadianYankee How about the following?

What's your favorite genre of **fiction**? Fairy tale or historical?

Comment: Why only give two (or any) choices for a 'favourite' genre? If that question were put to me, I would say 'neither'.

Comment: @Apollyon Yes, since you've specified that you are talking about fiction genres, you can then give those two options and it will make sense

Comment: If someone asked me: Which of these literary genres do you like - historical, crime, horror, sci-fi, or bodice-ripper?' I would see nothing wrong or difficult to understand.

Comment: In the OP it is actually "fairy tale" that sounds a bit odd to me. Mostly because the items marked "fairy tale" don't have enough unifying elements for me to think of them as a genre. They are certainly a category of fiction, I'm just not sure "category of fiction" and "genre" are synonymous.

Comment: @Apollyon What are you actually asking that hasn't been answered already? Please edit your question to make it clear to us

Answer (score 1):

The name of the literary genre is ***historical fiction***, so I wouldn't use *historical* on its own.

> ***Historical fiction*** is ***a literary genre*** in which the plot takes place in a setting located in the past. Although the term is
> commonly used as a synonym for the historical novel, it can also be
> applied to other types of narrative, including theatre, opera, cinema,
> and television, as well as video games and graphic novels. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_fiction))

So your sentence should be

> What's your favorite literary genre? Fairy tale or ***historical fiction***?

Only in a particular context where ***fiction*** is evidently implied you can maybe omit it, as it occurs in this [*list of writing genres on Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_writing_genres).